# How to save session in ActiveRecord instead of cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to save session to ActiveRecord instead of cookie. I'm proceeding with reference to this site
[Active Record Session Store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store)

```
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
```

↓
bundle install
↓

```
rails generate active_record:session_migration
```

then,
error

```
/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-session_store-1.1.3/lib/activerecord/session_store.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `config' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I got this error. I tried:

/config/initializers/session_store.rb（File created by myself）

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: "_#{Rails.application.class.parent_name.downcase}_session"
```

After writing, again

```
rails generate active_record:session_migration
```

I did, but after all

```
/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-session_store-1.1.3/lib/activerecord/session_store.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `config' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

environment
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin20]
Rails 6.1.0
sqlite3 3.32.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example in config looks a bit outdated (for an older rails version).

Try `Rails.application.config.session_store` in place of `AppName::Application.config.session_store`